# Mongo: Two instances, same port?

Tags: mongodb

So I installed MongoDB as a windows service. It starts and works as expected.

Then while I was playing around I decided to add a new data directory and, from the command line, start an instance of mongod.exe pointing at this new data directory.

So at this point I have one instance running as a service and one instance running from a command prompt (or that's how it appears).

I then connected with my gui tool to localhost and got the server instance.

Looking at the details they both appear to be running on the same port (27017).

My questions are:

Are there really two instances running on the same port or is it one instance with two data directories?

If it is two instances how can they share the same port?

If it is two instances is there away to connect to either one?

If it is one instance then are both data directories being used?

If it is one instance and both data directories are being used what is the second one being used for?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there really two instances running on the same port or is it one
>   instance with two data directories?

No, two instances cannot run in the same port. You would have got an error when you started the second mongod on the same port.

> If it is two instances how can they share the same port?

No, same port cannot be shared between two different instances of mongod on the same machine. Also, there cannot be two data directories for a single instance of mongod.

> If it is two instances is there away to connect to either one?

Check the service status, if it is running or not also you can check the mongod.log for the current state of the service. For command prompt instance you should be able to see the status in command prompt itself if `--fork` option is not enabled.

> If it is one instance then are both data directories being used?

No, there cannot be two data directories for a single instance of mongod.

> If it is one instance and both data directories are being used what is
>   the second one being used for?

No, there cannot be two data directories for a single instance of mongod.